# Поиск расположения .ехе файла

Tags: c#, файлы, exe

Добрый день.
Есть ли какие то методы для поиска местонахождения `.ехе` файла в С#. 
Нужно программно узнать месторасположение `sqlcmd.exe` 
Если искать через реестр, то на разных компьютерах он находится в разных местах.
Спасибо.

Comment: Что Вы с ним собираетесь делать после нахождения-то?

Comment: Нужно сохранить адрес в переменную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу посоветовать следующее:

- Поиск по путям в `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables("path")`

  ```
  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path")  
  .Split(';')  
  .Select(dir => Path.Combine(dir, "sqlcmd.exe"))  
  .FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);
  ```
- Поискать в реестре.
- Попросить пользователя указать путь.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Эээ... `Process.Start`? А если надо будет найти путь к `format.com`?

Comment: @VladD, ну, я бы не посоветовал в этом случае)

Хотя, конечно, Process.Start надо было в последнюю очередь использовать...

Comment: А почему бы не начать с

    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path").Split(';')

?

Comment: Как я понимаю, далее выискивать по указанным путям интересующий нас файл? Да, вариант... Переменные окружения сразу в голову не приходят почему-то...

А как, кстати, грамотно вот такой путь обработать? %TFSPowerToolDir%

Comment: @Spawn: По идее, точно так же: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TFSPowerToolDir")`.

Comment: Должно получится такое:

    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("path")
               .Split(';')
               .Select(dir => Path.Combine(dir, "sqlcmd.exe"))
               .FirstOrDefault(File.Exists)

(исправил, раньше была ошибка: `':'` вместо `';'`)

Comment: Спасибо... я не обратил внимания

Comment: Ошибка была у меня, я исправил (и в ответе тоже).